# Mathematical definition for limit points of a set approaching their own limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definition

**What are *standard* definitions for the following?**

Suppose we have $\{{1}/{2^x}:x\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

This has a limit point of zero but sets such as $\left\{{1}/{2^x}+{1}/{2^y}:y\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ have limit points in the form $\left\{{1}/{2^a}:a\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ and $\left\{{1}/{2^a}:a\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ has a limit point $\left\{0\right\}$. I will call $\left\{{1}/{2^a}:a\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ a "first-order" limit point and $\{0\}$ the "second order" limit points.

I assume sets that are dense in their domain have "infinite-order" limit points.

**What is the rigorous definition for "nth order" limit points?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the concept of the [derived set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)) fits your question.

Suppose we have a topological space $X$. Let's assume that $X$ is metrizable (which for purposes of your problem has the desirable effect that "convergence of sequences" is very closely linked to the topology).

The *derived set* $X' \subset X$ is what you get from $X$ by removing the subset of isolated points, meaning those $x \in X$ such that $\{x\}$ is an open subset. I think this set $X'$ fits the notion of "first order limit points" in the sense you are saying.

Now we can repeat this: you can take the derived set of the derived set, and you get $X''$ which is the set of second order limit points. And now you can continue inductively: assuming $X,X',X'',...,X^{(k-1)}$ are defined, let $X^{(k)}=(X^{(k-1)})'$, which becomes the set of $k$th order limit points.

Now is where it gets fun: define
$$X^\omega = \cap_{k = 1}^\infty X^{(k)}
$$
The symbol $\omega$ represents the first infinite ordinal, and $X^\omega$ is the set of $\omega^{\text{th}}$ order limit points.

And if you know about the general theory of [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), you can continue with transfinite induction, i.e. induction with ordinals. For example you have $X^{\omega+1} = (X^\omega)'$ and so on to $X^{\omega+k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$, and then
$$X^{2\omega} = \cap_{k=1}^\infty X^{\omega+k}
$$
and so on and on.

I believe that it is accurate to say that the theory of ordinal numbers was actually discovered by Cantor through his investigations of the effects of interating and intersecting the derived set operation as I've describe, as applied to subsets of the number line. He invented the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) as a set which is its own derived set, i.e. it has no isolated points, and yet it also contains no intervals.